# How to delete YAML::Node?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I'm using YAML-CPP to parse a yaml string.  It returns YAML::Node, I think it's currently a 32-byte container?  Mainly m_pMemory and m_pNode.

```
node = YAML::Load(ystr);
```

At the end of this function, I would like to release the memory accessed by node. Since node is a 32-byte object, it will be gone when it gone out of scope? But how do I release the space accessed by m_pMemory and m_pNode in it?  Or do I need to do that at all?  Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

`YAML::Node` manages its own memory, so when the object goes out of scope, the memory will be freed.